Firebase Phone Auth Error : auth/operation-not-allowed The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project
I have configured firebase phone auth several times on wordpress using the same plugin. Suddenly on a new project , I am now getting an error message,
"auth/operation-not-allowed
The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section."
Please help me with solutions.
I tried deleting the project and starting over again but still its the same.

This error message has been covered a few times before and can have different causes. Without seeing a Minimal, Reproducible Example, it's hard to say what's causing it for you though.
